# Не идет чтение строки и последующее ее удаление в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Всем привет! задача: Нужно в тхт прочитать строку, выполнить определенную манипуляцию и удалить строку. Далее- перейти на следующую строку. Вроде бы просто, но что то не получается- чтение проходит, а удаление- нет. что я делаю не так?

```
myfile = input ('Enter txt: ')
myfile2 = open (myfile, 'r+')
for line in myfile2:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    #делаем что-то со строкой
    delme = line.replace(line,'')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С файлами так не получится, т.к. когда вы считываете из файла, вы получаете не умный объект, а набор байтов, поэтому нужно самостоятельно записать в файл нужные изменения.

Поэтому, предлагаю самый простой способ, который подойдет почти для любого случай: считать из файла все данные, отредактировать и переписать файл.

Пример замены в файле строки `Finish push` на `Finish!` (в вашем случае, просто не нужно добавлять строку в список/файл, чтобы ее удалить):

```
line_list = []

with open('text') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('Finish push', 'Finish!')
        line_list.append(line)

with open('text', mode='w') as f:
    for line in line_list:
        f.write(line)
```

Файл `text`:

```
525
Cycle commit #525
Finish push


528
Cycle commit #528
Finish push


530
Cycle commit #530
Finish push


532
Cycle commit #532
Finish push


534
Cycle commit #534
Finish push
```

---

**PS.**

`with open('text') as f` прекрасно заменяется на:

```
f = open('text')
...
f.close()
```

---

**PPS.**

Другой случай, это когда файл не влезает в оперативную память, тогда можно организовать такое:

1. Открыть файл `text` в режиме чтения и файл `new_text`
2. В цикле считывать построчно из `text`, редактировать и записывать в `new_text`
3. Закрыть оба файла

Comment: Открыть файл text в режиме чтения и файл new_text
В цикле считывать по строчно из text, редактировать и записывать в new_text
Закрыть оба файла - вот так наверно и поступлю, так как файлы большие, хотя хотелось бы делать операции в 1 файле (удобно)

Comment: @dimahimma, тогда после закрытия файлов, `text` удалите, а `new_text` переименуйте в `text`

Comment: не факт что за один присест я обработаю весь файл, так что придется из text удалять пройденные строки из new_text